# Error running iOS app from shoutem v5

Tags: shoutem

After I do a `shoutem run-ios`, the app builds fine and loads the splash page.  As soon as it goes to the main screen, I get the red error screen with this message:

> console.error: "Unhandled promise rejction"

In the logs, I see the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of null
>       at launchEditor (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/util/launchEditor.js:153:29)
>       at Object.handle (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/openStackFrameInEditorMiddleware.js:17:7)
>       at next (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
>       at Object.handle (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/getDevToolsMiddleware.js:74:7)
>       at next (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
>       at Object.handle (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/getDevToolsMiddleware.js:74:7)
>       at next (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
>       at Object.compression [as handle] (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/compression/index.js:205:5)
>       at next (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/Users/njdeveloper/.shoutem/platforms/build/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/loadRawBodyMiddleware.js:20:5)

Comment: Do you have any custom extensions installed?

Comment: I am also facing this same problem with react native. Unable to get any solution so far.